# onActivityResult() not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

`onActivityResult()` is not getting called. Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to

    Log.e("CALLED", "OnActivity Result");

    if (requestCode == TEAM_SELECTED_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                 mySelectedTeam = getIntent().getStringExtra("teamName");
                txtSelectTeamCreateMatch.setText(mySelectedTeam);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's I'm starting the `SelectTeamActivity`:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CreateMatch.this,SelectTeamActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, TEAM_SELECTED_REQUEST_CODE);
//overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);

Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("teamID", teamDataList.get(position).getTeamId().toString());
intent.putExtra("teamName", teamDataList.get(position).getTeamName().toString());
setResult(1, intent);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

onActivityResult called but using wrong intent reference to get data from result intent :

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("teamName")
```

Replace with this :

```
data.getStringExtra("teamName")
```

Here data is result intent.

Answer (score 87):

### Option 1 :

If you're calling `startActivityForResult()` from the `Fragment` then you should call `startActivityForResult()` and not `getActivity().startActivityForResult()`, as it will result in `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult()`.

If you're not sure where you're calling on `startActivityForResult()` and how you will be calling methods.

### Option 2:

Since `Activity` gets the result of `onActivityResult()`, you will need to override the `Activity`'s `onActivityResult()` and call `super.onActivityResult()` to propagate to the respective `Fragment` for unhandled results codes or for all.

If above 2 options do not work, then refer option 3 as it will definitely work.

### Option 3 :

Explicit call from `Fragment` to `onActivityResult()` function as follows

In parent `Activity` class, override the `onActivityResult()` and even override the same in `Fragment` class and call as the following code.

In parent class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dualPane);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In child class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   //in fragment class callback
}
```

Comment: if you satisfied with my answer,can you please accept it?

Comment: @AkashMoradiya, What to do if all 3 didn't work? 
2nd one worked when I was using `GoogleSignIn`, but none works when I create intent. This happens within the same fragment (GoogleSignIn works but not the intent). I overrode both parent Activity function and the fragment's one

Comment: doesn't work for me. Tried option 1 and option 2.

Answer (score 17):

I solved my problem by removing `android:noHistory="true"` from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I don't even have android:noHistory="true" in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue. My calling activity was 'singleInstance'. Removing that solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you, you're great! It also behaves differently on different API levels. KitKat didn't like my result activity being singleInstance, but Android N didn't mind at all. Really strange.

Comment: @ClarenceLeung What the answer says basically. Instead of making it `singleInstance` make it `singleTop` or `standard`.

Comment: wasn't working for me because my activity was `singleTask`. removing it solved my issue as well.

Comment: Thanks, man! Looks like it is not working with `singleInstance` since Android M.

Comment: it cannot work with `singleInstance` because it starts a new Task and within it there is no Activity to go back to

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem and my issue was about `requestCode` parameter which was set to -1 in `startActivityForResult` method.
So when I changed `requestCode` value to 1 or 0 `onActivityResult` started getting called.

Comment: Thank you; this was exactly my problem. The docs are really unclear on this; they say "`requestCode`: int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits" - for this reason I deliberately set the `requestCode` to -1 as I don't need it to be returned to the `onActivityResult`, but in fact the `onActivityResult` does not even get called in this case, which is really not clear from the docs

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and I'm surprised none of the solutions I've looked at have mentioned the following:

The value of the constant RESULT_OK is -1, and if you give the value of 1 in the method setResult, then the resultcode wouldn't be equal to the RESULT_OK and the condition wouldn't get processed. 
I hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly that was my problem.

Comment: Hmm, we usually call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)`, so hardly can face this situation.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing pradip tilala's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56437907/10787285/), I have solved my problem by removing below line from AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved that by adding these parameters to activity:

```
AlwaysRetainTaskState = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop
```

Answer (score 1):

After referring answer of @spgodara.

I have below `AndroidManifest.xml` for my `SecondActivity` class:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeHome"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

I have put simple `Toast` to find when callback `onActivityResult` of `MainActivity` is being called. I found that is just called on create of `SecondActivity` (On opening of the `SecondActivity`). **It's working fine on Redmi Note 3 device** with Marshmallow, **but not working on Kitkat device**.

After removing below the line from AndroidManifest.xml deceleration mentioned above:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and calling intent like below worked for me:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed this line and its working fine.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Thanks for hint.

Comment: this should be the answer. verified in https://github.com/zhangtemplar/SMSForward