# onActivityResult not getting called in an activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I know this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988038/onactivityresult-not-called) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689404/onactivityresult-method-not-being-called-android). But I am doing all that is mentioned in these questions but still my `onActivityResult()` method is not getting called.

What am I doing wrong here?

**caller activity**

```
private void launchAddressActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, AddressActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 2 && data != null) {
        if (validIntent(data)) {
            addressTextView.setText(
                    MessageFormat.format("{0},{1}\n{2}",
                            data.getStringExtra(UserConstants.USER_ADDRESS_1),
                            data.getStringExtra(UserConstants.USER_ADDRESS_2),
                            data.getStringExtra(UserConstants.USER_ADDRESS_LANDMARK)));
       }
    }
}
```

**callee activity**

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(UserConstants.USER_ADDRESS_1, address1.getText().toString());
resultIntent.putExtra(UserConstants.USER_ADDRESS_2, address2.getText().toString());
resultIntent.putExtra(UserConstants.USER_ADDRESS_LANDMARK, landmark.getText().toString());
setResult(2, resultIntent);
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vuclip.liqyd">

<application
    android:name=".LiqydApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ui.login.LoginRegistrationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--<activity android:name=".ui.login.LoginRegistrationActivity" />-->
    <activity android:name=".ui.gallary.GallaryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.address.AddressActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.order_details.OrderDetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.payment.PaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.MenuHandingActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: yes I am not getting that log message. setResult in AddressActivity is getting called I verified that.

Comment: I tried all that. it is absolutely frustrating.

Comment: nada, nothing gets printed except for some android junk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163933/discussion-between-ezio-and-pskink).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
setResult(2, resultIntent);
```

to

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

And,

```
if (resultCode == 2 && data != null) {
```

to

```
if (requestCode == 2 && data != null) {
```

That would be the right way to use `startActivityForResult`.

**UPD**: as we found in chat the reason to fail here after fixing what described above was mistakenly using RESULT_OK as tracking code here `startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);`, the `onActivityResult` callback was not called in this case. After changing it to `startActivityForResult(intent, 2);` everything finally started working.

Comment: The thing is you have to use RESULT_OK when you are passing result from another activity. We can use any requestCode you want in your calling activity.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `finish();` after line `setResult(2, resultIntent);`

The `finish()` will finishing the current activity and return to previous activity.

Comment: I cannot update, SO is giving me an error saying, your post contains all code.